# How populate an user with the article posted by user?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to catch the article who correspond at the right user. But I don't know why it doesn't work. Did I forgot something ?

**User Model:**

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please tell us your name!']
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required:true
  },
[...]
  articles: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref:'Article'
  }],
});
```

**Article Model:**

```
const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Un article doit avoir un titre.'],
    unique: [true, 'Un article doit être unique'],
    trim: true,
  },
[...]
  author: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref:'User'
  }],

});
```

**user routes:**

```
router.get("/:id", factory.getOne(User, {path: "articles", model:'Article', select: '-__v'}));
```

**factory controller:**

```
exports.getOne = (Model, popOptions) =>
  catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    let query = Model.findById(req.params.id);
    if (popOptions) query = query.populate(popOptions);
    const doc = await query;

    if (!doc) {
      return next(new AppError('No document found with that ID', 404));
    }

    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        data: doc
      }
    });
  });
```

**And in the result I have:**

```
articles: []
email: "xxx"
firstName: "xxx"
job: "xxx"
lastName: "xxx"
photo: "default.jpg"
role: "user"
__v: 0
_id: "5fbc04616c5478528c73e2a9"
```

Example of one article who is populated by an user but in post article route I put in author the current id. I use this getOne function and it's populate by the user who create the article:

```
article: false
author: Array(1)
0: {photo: "default.jpg", articles: Array(0), _id: "xxx", lastName: "xxx", firstName: "xxx", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
cardclasse: "btn-green"
created_at: "2020-11-24T10:56:10.738Z"
description: "tips"
fatclasse: "FAT__BCG"
help: false
slug: "test-p1"
tag: "xxx"
tips: true
title: "xxx"
userId: "5fbc04616c5478528c73e2a9"
__v: 0
_id: "5fbcea80e9a88d1b24d01448"
```

Thanks by advance :)

I'm pretty new in NodeJS so sorry if it's an absurd question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you don't need to add a field called articles on userschema. And on the Article Model you need to change type of author to object as like.

```
const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Un article doit avoir un titre.'],
    unique: [true, 'Un article doit être unique'],
    trim: true,
    },

   author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref:'User'
  },
});
```

But if you have schema where article can be added by multiple user than your model is okay for articles.

If you want to find all the articles by the specific user then use findfunction along with populate on articles schema.
for that you can use something like..

```
articleModel.find({ author: { $in: yourauthorid } }).populate("author");
```

This will list all articles by specific user on array.
I did removed [...] from model as i couldn't understand the usage. but this should solve your problem.